# fourth entry causes df.to_sql fail

Tags: python, sql, database, oracle, dataframe

I have a smallish dataframe.  I keep getting errors when I try to write the dataframe to a database.  I tried cutting out some of the data, and was able to succeed with 3 entries, but the 4th failed.  Let me show what is happening more clearly.

I take a piece of my dataframe:

```
good_asmnt = ('LCC1', 'OQC1', 'QLC1' )
tiny_split = this_split [ this_split [ 'COURSE_NUMBER' ].isin ( good_asmnt )]
tiny_split
```

gives me:

```
-------------------------------
| | COURSE_NUMBER  | bin_var  |
-------------------------------
|0| LCC1           |    0     |
|1| OQC1           |    1     |
|2| QLC1           |    1     |
-------------------------------
```

Then I run:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('oracle://wgubi:w3d0stats@192.168.52.13:1522/BIWH')
tiny_split.to_sql('mdb_model_out', engine, if_exists='replace')
```

Checking in the database shows the table is there with the correct data.

Now I add an entry:

```
good_asmnt = ('LCC1', 'OQC1', 'QLC1', 'MYC1' )
tiny_split = this_split [ this_split [ 'COURSE_NUMBER' ].isin ( good_asmnt )]
tiny_split
```

gives me:

```
-------------------------------
| | COURSE_NUMBER  | bin_var  |
-------------------------------
|0| LCC1           |    0     |
|1| OQC1           |    1     |
|2| QLC1           |    1     |
|3| MYC1           |    0     |
-------------------------------
```

Then I run:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('oracle://wgubi:w3d0stats@192.168.52.13:1522/BIWH')
tiny_split.to_sql('mdb_model_out', engine, if_exists='replace')
```

And get an error -

> TypeError: expecting string, unicode or buffer object

In the database the table is there, and all the data is gone.

I have 351 entries I want to write to the database, and don't want to move them 3 at a time.

Answer (score 0):

A friend took a look and came up with a resolution.

Part 1 - One column name was all caps, the other lower case.  She made them both lower case.

Part 2 - one column is numeric, but was an object in the dataframe.  She converted this column to float64.

The to_sql now works.  I don't have any explanation as to why it would work for a few rows, or why the capitalization made a difference for more than 3 entries.